# Check hypertext reference of each element in link and compare with adserver IP

Tags: python, selenium

I am making an ad-blocking program.This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = input('Enter URL to detect ads from: ')

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://'+url)

all_iframes = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")
if len(all_iframes) > 0:
    print("" + "Ads Found\n")
    browser.execute_script("""
    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe"); 
    for(var i = 0, max = elems.length; i < max; i++)
         {
             elems[i].hidden=true;
         }
                      """)
    print('Total Ads: ' + str(len(all_iframes)))
else:
    print('No Ads found')
```

My question is that is there any way of checking the hypertext reference of the iframes and comparing them with the adserver IP's on [this](http://pgl.yoyo.org/adservers/iplist.php?ipformat=plain&showintro=1) page?

Comment: Sorry, are  you trying to compare the iframe names with ip address on the other page? Or trying to compare some element within each of the iframe with the other page?

Comment: Sorry, I am comparing the iframe names with the ad servers listed on the page. I will edit my question now

Comment: edited the link to show IP adresses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following solution, but I'm not sure that this will cover all cases (I have no possibility to check it for now):

```
import requests 
import sockets
from selenium import webdriver

url = input('Enter URL to detect ads from: ')

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://'+url)

all_iframes = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")

# Get IP list of ad servers with GET HTTP request (you might need to use "pip install requests")
list_of_ad_servers = requests.get('http://pgl.yoyo.org/adservers/iplist.php?ipformat=&showintro=1&mimetype=plaintext').text.split()
if len(all_iframes) > 0:
    for i in all_iframes:
        try:
            source = i.get_attribute('src')
            if source.startswith('http'):  # to get only 3rd-party links
                # Get IP of source link and check if it present in ad servers list
                if socket.gethostbyname(source.split('/')[2]) in list_of_ad_servers:
                    print('This is advertisement iframe!')
                    browser.execute_script('arguments[0].hidden=true;', i)
        except: pass
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but can you tell me where to put it in my code? sorry about that

Comment: Answer updated. I guess this should be complete code. Let me know in case of any issues as

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I'm not well versed with Python syntax but can answer from java perspective which you can extend to your test.

Got to ipAdd site, get the pagesource.

```
driver.get("http://pgl.yoyo.org/as/serverlist.php?hostformat=adblockplus");
String pageSrc=driver.getpagesource(); //Get page source
List<String> ipList=pageSrc.split("\\||*\\^");Split based on start and end character
```

On your test website, get the iframe webelements and compare with ipAdd list

```
  List<Webelement> all_iframes = driver.findElements(by.tag_name("iframe"));//Creates list of iframe webelements
 for(Webelement iframe:all_iframes){
    if(//Compare iframe.getAttribute("name") with ipaddress list){  //check whether ipaddress list contains frame name
      SOPL("Found");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Note that not every `iframe` has attribute `name`. Also `name` is a simple string, like `"main_frame"` while `IPv4` is a sequence of digits, 4-byte address, e.g. `192.168.1.1`- there is no sense in comparing them